# Use Commands with RadRibbonView Buttons in C# and not XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I am trying to get MVVM (pretty new to it) and RadRibbonView to work together. Problem is, I was working with a standard WPF application with an MVVM model.

In the XAML file I previously had.

```
<Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.FileMenu}">
                <MenuItem Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.FileMenuNewWorkflow}" Command="{Binding Path=NewWorkflowCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+N"/>
                <MenuItem Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.FileMenuNewService}" Command="{Binding Path=NewServiceCommand}" InputGestureText="Shift+Ctrl+N"/>
                <MenuItem Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.FileMenuOpen}" Command="{Binding Path=OpenWorkflowCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+O"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.FileMenuSave}" Command="{Binding Path=SaveWorkflowCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+S"/>
                <MenuItem Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.FileMenuSaveAs}" Command="{Binding Path=SaveAsWorkflowCommand}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.FileMenuSaveAll}" Command="{Binding Path=SaveAllWorkflowsCommand}" InputGestureText="Shift+Ctrl+S"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.FileMenuAddReference}" Command="{Binding Path=AddReferenceCommand}"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.FileMenuClose}" Command="{Binding Path=CloseWorkflowCommand}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="{x:Static properties:Resources.FileMenuCloseAll}" Command="{Binding Path=CloseAllWorkflowsCommand}"/>
                <Separator/>            
        </Menu>
```

RelayCommand.cs

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Action<object> execute;
        private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
            : this(execute, null)
        {
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            if (execute == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
            }

            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;           
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return this.canExecute == null ? true : this.canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.execute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

As you can see the Command id was well defined. I wanted to add Ribbon to this and selected RibbonView from telerik WPF UI. Picked the Paint with MVVM model.

Converted the Menu to Ribbon

```
<telerik:RadRibbonView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ribbonView" ApplicationName="MyApp" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
                               ApplicationButtonContent="File" Title="{x:Static properties:Resources.RibbonViewTitle}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabTemplate}"
                               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               MinimizeButtonVisibility="Visible" HelpButtonVisibility="Visible">
```

In the MainWindowModelView The following is defined. SplitButtonViewModel inherits from ButtonViewModel.

```
private GroupViewModel GetFilesGroup()
    {
        GroupViewModel fileItems = new GroupViewModel();
        fileItems.Text = "File";
        SplitButtonViewModel newFile = new SplitButtonViewModel();
        newFile.Text = "New";
        newFile.Size = ButtonSize.Large;
        newFile.LargeImage = GetPath("MVVM/new.png");
        fileItems.Buttons.Add(newFile);


        SplitButtonViewModel openFile = new SplitButtonViewModel();
        openFile.Text = "Open";
        openFile.Size = ButtonSize.Large;
        openFile.LargeImage = GetPath("MVVM/open.png");
        fileItems.Buttons.Add(openFile);

        ButtonGroupViewModel buttonsGroup = new ButtonGroupViewModel();
        buttonsGroup.Buttons.Add(GetButton("save", "Save"));
        buttonsGroup.Buttons.Add(GetButton("SaveAll", "Save All"));
        buttonsGroup.Buttons.Add(GetButton("SaveAs", "Save As"));

        fileItems.Buttons.Add(buttonsGroup);
        return fileItems;
    }
```

My current ButtonViewModel from the telerik MVVM Ribbon example is

```
    public class ButtonViewModel : ViewModelBase
        {
            private String text;
            private ButtonSize size;
            private string smallImage;
            private string largeImage;
//perhaps work something with this...
            private RelayCommand command;    

            /// <summary>
            ///     Gets or sets Text.
            /// </summary>
            public String Text
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.text;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (this.text != value)
                    {
                        this.text = value;
                        this.OnPropertyChanged("Text");
                    }
                }
            }

            public ButtonSize Size
            {
                get
                {
                    return size;
                }
                set
                {
                    size = value;
                }
            }

            public string SmallImage
            {
                get
                {
                    return smallImage;
                }
                set
                {
                    smallImage = value;
                }
            }

            public string LargeImage
            {
                get
                {
                    return largeImage;
                }
                set
                {
                    largeImage = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

So all the creation of the Groups is in the ModelView. The problem is I am not sure how to get the Command working. I have a RelayCommand class which takes care of the commands.

From the following link: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radribbonview/how-to/howto-use-commands-with-radribbonview-buttons
Is it possible to just call the class RelayCommand (basically same as the example from the link), so I do not have to change much and just invoke the command from the above function? Something like openFile.Execute() or something.

Most of the questions were how to connect XAML to Commands. All the menu items are now in C# and wanted a command definition there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can check here how I would do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44369604/communication-with-ribbon-bar-using-mvvm

Comment: Thank you. I think again the binding is in the XAML file. I was looking at invoking or binding in the C# file as the group buttons are all defined in the ModelView class.